# Apache config: "no listening sockets available"

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I'm trying to configure apache2 (it's configured inside Enfinity Suite), but something seems to go wrong with the configuration.

If I set:

> Listen 86

It says:

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:86 no listening sockets available, shutting down

If I set:

> Listen 127.0.0.1:86

It says:

> (OS 10013) An attempt was made to access a socet in a way forbidden by its access pemissions. :make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:86 no listening sockets available, shutting down

If I set a port higher than 450, lets say Listen 127.0.0.1:8080, it says:

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:450 no listening sockets available, shutting down

Can someone please clarify what's going on? (Some Windows policies?)

Comment: You may want to post this at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @qroberts, PLEASE do not ask folks to repost their question. Questions will be moved automatically if applicable. Thanks! (Apart from that: *Server Fault [is for](http://serverfault.com/faq) system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your apache process will run with an effective user different than the user starting it. Make sure, that the user starting it has the permission to create listening sockets (for ports <1024 this should only be root). Also make sure, that the port you want to use is not already taken (with `netstat -an` ).

It don't have a clue about the difference of the error messages.

Comment: The actual thing was that my administrator configured apache and started it (being a different user) so I had no chance binding to the same ports. Though I still don't get why while specifying 8080 apache tried 450.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're supposed to start apache as root and it lowers its own rights, but it has to be root so it can bind to ports less than 1024 as mentioned above.

you can also try netstat -nap  | grep LISTEN
in linux and look for something listening on that port and the -p will tell you which program is already bound to that port.
if not using linux, there are other tools like lsof that will tell you this information just not as cleanly.

Comment: The OP mentioned "Some windows policies" so this is probably Apache2 on Windows.

Comment: ahh right. Missed that. They can of course install cygwin. Solves all sorts of I-can't-do-that-in-windows-easily problems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Those errors you're getting are from Winsock. [A quick primer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx):

- **OS 10013**: Access denied
- **OS 10048**: Address already in use

You do need to be running Apache2 as an Administrator-equivalent user in order to bind to ports under 1000, but your attempt to bind to :8080 should have worked even as a normal user. It is possible that something else is camping that port and you got unlucky. You can find out what that is by running `netstat -ano |find "LIST"` from a cmd prompt (note that's not -anp like with Linux). That will give you the process ID of what's camping that port, which you can then look up in Task Manager.

An outside possibility is that what you're seeing is an attempt to launch Apache2 twice for some reason. The first instance correctly binds to the right ports, but the second instance can't because the first one is stuck on it. If this is the case, you may have some doubled-up log-files with timestamps really close together.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was edit the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file in this way:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf


NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
Listen 192.168.1.11:3001




<IfModule ssl_module>
NameVirtualHost *:443
        Listen 443

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I hope that can helps anyone. Bye